# Implementation of ceil function in C

Tags: c, ceil

I have two questions regarding `ceil()` function..

1. The `ceil()` function is implemented in C. If I use `ceil(3/2)`, it works fine. But when I use `ceil(count/2)`, if value of count is 3, then it gives compile time error.

   > /tmp/ccA4Yj7p.o(.text+0x364): In function `FrontBackSplit': : undefined reference to`ceil' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

   How to use the ceil function in second case? Please suggest.
2. How can I implement my own ceil function in C. Please give some basic guidelines.

Thanks.

Comment: ceil(3/2) = 1.0, ceil(3/2.0) = 2.0 -- see if you can work out why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ceil()` function is implemented in the math library, `libm.so`.  By default, the linker does not link against this library when invoked via the gcc frontend.  To link against that library, pass `-lm` on the command line to gcc:

```
gcc main.c -lm
```

Comment: Note that this is not true on all platforms.  Some platforms do not require linking against libm to get math functions.

Comment: Hi this works fine for me.. Thanks.. 

What is this parameter -lm?

Comment: @RBA, "-lm" means to link against the library "libm.so" or "libm.dylib" or "m.dll", depending on your platform.

Answer (score 6):

Try this out:

```
#define CEILING_POS(X) ((X-(int)(X)) > 0 ? (int)(X+1) : (int)(X))
#define CEILING_NEG(X) (int)(X)
#define CEILING(X) ( ((X) > 0) ? CEILING_POS(X) : CEILING_NEG(X) )
```

Check out the link for comments, proof and discussion:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ceiling-function-c-programming-637404/

Thanks to Vilhelm Gray and carveone for pointing out that the linked definition of `CEILING_NEG(X)` is incorrect.

Comment: This is incorrect for negative values: ceiling always returns the smallest integer **greater than** or equal to the argument given (which for negative numbers means toward zero rather than away).

Comment: Test test and test again. ceil(-6.2) is -6. The macros give -7. It's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The prototype of the [ceil](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ceil.html) function is:

```
double ceil(double)
```

My guess is that the type of your variable `count` is not of type double. To use ceil in C, you would write:

```
#include <math.h>
// ...
double count = 3.0;
double result = ceil(count/2.0);
```

In C++, you can use `std::ceil` from <cmath>; std::ceil is overloaded to support multiple types:

```
#include <cmath>
// ...
double count = 3.0;
double result = std::ceil(count/2.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
#define (x < 0 ? (int)x : (int)x + 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
double ceil (double x) {
    if (x > LONG_MAX) return x; // big floats are all ints
    return ((long)(x+(0.99999999999999997)));
}
```