# Implement ceil() in C

Tags: c, floating-point, implementation, ceil

I want to implement my own `ceil()` in `C`. Searched through the libraries for source code & found [here](http://code.google.com/p/dexandroid/source/search?q=ceil.c&origq=ceil.c&btnG=Search%20Trunk), but it seems pretty difficult to understand. I want clean & elegant code.

I also searched on SO, found some answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796639/implementation-of-ceil-function-in-c). None of the answer seems to be correct. One of the answer is:

```
#define CEILING_POS(X) ((X-(int)(X)) > 0 ? (int)(X+1) : (int)(X))
#define CEILING_NEG(X) ((X-(int)(X)) < 0 ? (int)(X-1) : (int)(X))
#define CEILING(X) ( ((X) > 0) ? CEILING_POS(X) : CEILING_NEG(X) )
```

AFAIK, the return type of the `ceil()` is not int. Will macro be type-safe here?
Further, will the above implementation work for negative numbers?

What will be the best way to implement it?

Can you provide the clean code?

Comment: Macros are, generally, _never_ type safe. They are also prone to unexpected side-effects (e.g. passing `x++` as parameter may increase `x` multiple times depending on macro).

Comment: It might be implemented by a compiler builtin, or by some assembly routine. I won't try to reimplement `ceil` without careful understanding of compiler internals, processor architecture, and IEEE representation.

Comment: I understand x+x for raising overflow or nan, but don't understand why reference code want to raise an inexact flag (huge+x)? If x is integer, then ceil(x) is exactly x, if x has a fraction part, then ceil(x) is well known and representable exactly too, or did I miss something?

Comment: Oops, forgot to read the comment "Inexact flag raised if x not equal to ceil(x).", since all rounding function are exact, this usage makes sense and might be dictated by some standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro you quoted definitely won't work correctly for numbers that are greater than `INT_MAX` but which can still be represented exactly as a double.

The only way to implement `ceil()` correctly (assuming you can't implement it using an equivalent assembly instruction) is to do bit-twiddling on the binary representation of the floating point number, as is done in the `s_ceil.c` source file behind your first link. Understanding how the code works requires an understanding of the floating point representation of the underlying platform -- the representation is most probably going to be [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) -- but there's no way around this.

Edit:

Some of the complexities in `s_ceil.c` stem from the special cases it handles (NaNs, infinities) and the fact that it needs to do its work without being able to assume that a 64-bit integral type exists.

The basic idea of all the bit-twiddling is to mask off the fractional bits of the mantissa and add 1 to it if the number is greater than zero... but there's a bit of additional logic involved as well to make sure you do the right thing in all cases.

Here's a illustrative version of `ceil()` for floats that I cobbled together. Beware: This does *not* handle the special cases correctly and it is not tested extensively -- so don't actually use it. It does however serve to illustrate the principles involved in the bit-twiddling. I've tried to comment the routine extensively, but the comments do assume that you understand how floating point numbers are represented in IEEE 754 format.

```
union float_int
{
    float f;
    int i;
};

float myceil(float x)
{
    float_int val;
    val.f=x;

    // Extract sign, exponent and mantissa
    // Bias is removed from exponent
    int sign=val.i >> 31;
    int exponent=((val.i & 0x7fffffff) >> 23) - 127;
    int mantissa=val.i & 0x7fffff;

    // Is the exponent less than zero?
    if(exponent<0) 
    {   
        // In this case, x is in the open interval (-1, 1)
        if(x<=0.0f)
            return 0.0f;
        else
            return 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        // Construct a bit mask that will mask off the
        // fractional part of the mantissa
        int mask=0x7fffff >> exponent;

        // Is x already an integer (i.e. are all the
        // fractional bits zero?)
        if((mantissa & mask) == 0)
            return x;
        else
        {
            // If x is positive, we need to add 1 to it
            // before clearing the fractional bits
            if(!sign)
            {
                mantissa+=1 << (23-exponent);

                // Did the mantissa overflow?
                if(mantissa & 0x800000)
                {
                    // The mantissa can only overflow if all the
                    // integer bits were previously 1 -- so we can
                    // just clear out the mantissa and increment
                    // the exponent
                    mantissa=0;
                    exponent++;
                }
            }

            // Clear the fractional bits
            mantissa&=~mask;
        }
    }

    // Put sign, exponent and mantissa together again
    val.i=(sign << 31) | ((exponent+127) << 23) | mantissa;

    return val.f;
}
```

Comment: Sure? What if x = 2^23-0.5... exponent=22, mantissa=0x7fffff, you add 1<<1 that is 0x800001, you clear ~mask 0x1, 0x800000, oh but this mantissa bit is set already in the shifted exponent, so I guess the result will be 2^22 instead of 2^23. Maybe you could try (((exponent+127) << 23) + mantissa)

Comment: @aka.nice Good catch, and your fix does appear to work. I guess that's why I said "beware"...

Comment: Yes, if it's single bug, it's already a good score given cyclomatic complexity ;) Also I just tried, you must declare union float_int val; in pure C.

Comment: @aka.nice Guess I speak C with a C++ accent... ;) I've given the bug some more thought. It can actually happen for much smaller numbers than 2^23-0.5 -- essentially, the bug strikes whenever the mantissa overflows. 7.01f will, for example, trigger the bug. I've edited the code to hopefully fix this -- the fix you proposed should work, but I've chosen to handle mantissa overflow explicitly for clarity of exposition. Note that I've been able to get rid of the case `exponent==0` (which is essentially just a special case of mantissa overflow). Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: Various notes: If you want to do it this way, it's best to *not* separate out the component fields; that way the significand overflows into the exponent, which is what you want to happen anyway.  You need to add an early out if the exponent is large; otherwise your shifts become undefined.  Also a cute trick: instead of shifting 1 into the right position, you can just do `significand =  significand + mask & ~mask` which is usually more efficient.  Finally, you get the sign of zero wrong for small negative inputs.

Comment: Upon further consideration, adding `1 << (23-exponent)` is totally wrong -- it forces positive integer inputs to produce the wrong value.  You need to add `mask` instead.

Comment: @StephenCanon: "adding `1 << (23-exponent)` is totally wrong -- it forces positive integer inputs to produce the wrong value" Really? Integers are detected and don't even enter the block where the `1 << (23-exponent)` is added. I think what you're getting at is that if I added `mask` instead of `1 << (23-exponent)`, I could avoid having to special-case integers in the first place -- correct?

Comment: @StephenCanon: Thanks for all of the "various notes" you pointed out -- all of them very good information, and they underscore why I stressed that no one should actually use the code.

Comment: I would highly advise against using a union. Not only is it 100% not necessary, it is not 100% guaranteed to produce optimal code (though those days are long gone). The correct way to convert a float to a uint32_t is with a reinterpret_cast<float*>(&value);

Comment: There is also another bit shifting blunder. Never use a signed integer to shift the sign bit. This code is not portable one bit at all. Signed values use what is called arithmetic bit shifting, not logical bit (or barrel) shifting. When you use arithmetic bit shifts it preserves the sign bit. The reason for this is to do multiplication/division of negative powers of 2. Always use uint32_t type for conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing you will write is more elegant than using the standard library implementation.  No code at all is always more elegant than elegant code.

That aside, this approach has two major flaws:

- If `X` is greater than `INT_MAX + 1` or less than `INT_MIN - 1`, the behavior of your macro is undefined.  This means that your implementation may give incorrect results for nearly half of all floating-point numbers.  You will also raise the invalid flag, contrary to IEEE-754.
- It gets the edge cases for -0, +/-infinity, and nan wrong.  In fact, the only edge case it gets right is +0.

You *can* implement `ceil` in  manner similar to what you tried, like so (this implementation assumes IEEE-754 double precision):

```
#include <math.h>

double ceil(double x) {
    // All floating-point numbers larger than 2^52 are exact integers, so we
    // simply return x for those inputs.  We also handle ceil(nan) = nan here.
    if (isnan(x) || fabs(x) >= 0x1.0p52) return x;
    // Now we know that |x| < 2^52, and therefore we can use conversion to
    // long long to force truncation of x without risking undefined behavior.
    const double truncation = (long long)x;
    // If the truncation of x is smaller than x, then it is one less than the
    // desired result.  If it is greater than or equal to x, it is the result.
    // Adding one cannot produce a rounding error because `truncation` is an
    // integer smaller than 2^52.
    const double ceiling = truncation + (truncation < x);
    // Finally, we need to patch up one more thing; the standard specifies that
    // ceil(-small) be -0.0, whereas we will have 0.0 right now.  To handle this
    // correctly, we apply the sign of x to the result.
    return copysign(ceiling, x);
}
```

Something like that is about as elegant as you can get and still be correct.

---

I flagged a number of concerns with the (generally good!) implementation that Martin put in his answer.  Here's how I would implement his approach:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline uint64_t toRep(double x) {
    uint64_t r;
    memcpy(&r, &x, sizeof x);
    return r;
}

static inline double fromRep(uint64_t r) {
    double x;
    memcpy(&x, &r, sizeof x);
    return x;
}

double ceil(double x) {

    const uint64_t signbitMask  = UINT64_C(0x8000000000000000);
    const uint64_t significandMask = UINT64_C(0x000fffffffffffff);

    const uint64_t xrep = toRep(x);
    const uint64_t xabs = xrep & signbitMask;

    // If |x| is larger than 2^52 or x is NaN, the result is just x.
    if (xabs >= toRep(0x1.0p52)) return x;

    if (xabs < toRep(1.0)) {
        // If x is in (1.0, 0.0], the result is copysign(0.0, x).
        // We can generate this value by clearing everything except the signbit.
        if (x <= 0.0) return fromRep(xrep & signbitMask);
        // Otherwise x is in (0.0, 1.0), and the result is 1.0.
        else return 1.0;
    }

    // Now we know that the exponent of x is strictly in the range [0, 51],
    // which means that x contains both integral and fractional bits.  We
    // generate a mask covering the fractional bits.
    const int exponent = xabs >> 52;
    const uint64_t fractionalBits = significandMask >> exponent;

    // If x is negative, we want to truncate, so we simply mask off the
    // fractional bits.
    if (xrep & signbitMask) return fromRep(xrep & ~fractionalBits);

    // x is positive; to force rounding to go away from zero, we first *add*
    // the fractionalBits to x, then truncate the result.  The add may
    // overflow the significand into the exponent, but this produces the
    // desired result (zero significand, incremented exponent), so we just
    // let it happen.
    return fromRep(xrep + fractionalBits & ~fractionalBits);
}
```

One thing to note about this approach is that it does *not* raise the inexact floating-point flag for non-integral inputs.  That may or may not be a concern for your usage.  The first implementation that I listed does raise the flag.

Comment: +1 for "No code at all is always more elegant than elegant code" alone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a macrofunction is a good solution: it isn't type safe and there is a multi-evaluation of the arguments (side-effects). You should rather write a clean and elegant *function*.

Comment: Can you provide the clean and elegant code? I tried, but it doesn't work for some cases?

Comment: Well, you should examine the details of your implementation (see also the answer of FredOverflow here with IEEE754). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377412/ceil-function-how-can-we-implement-it-ourselves

Answer (score 0):

As I would have expected more jokes in answers, I will try a couple

```
#define CEILING(X) ceil(X)
```

Bonus: a macro with not so many side effects
If you don't care too much of negative zeroes

```
#define CEILING(X) (-floor(-(X)))
```

If you care of negative zero, then

```
#define CEILING(X) (NEGATIVE_ZERO - floor(-(X)))
```

Portable definition of NEGATIVE_ZERO left as an exercize....
Bonus, it will also set FP flags (OVERFLOW INVALID INEXACT)

Comment: I would have expected more comments on this one!