# Simulink generate code with unsupported istruction (ceil)

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

Generating code by Simulink (Matlab R2011A on MacOS 64bit) 
I got a problem: it uses `ceil` function inside the code, but it isn't supported on my target platform.
I'm generating using ERT, for Arm Cortex processor (on a Cypress PSoC).

Is it possible to solve this problem?

I tried the solution without success.
Also in Code Generation - Interface, I tried to disable floating-point or not-finite numbers... but in this way every signal of my project raises some errors (same behaviour also changing it data-type).

Really thanks to anyone suggests me what I can try to do

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have ceil… have you tried ceil(2.3) on matlab interface? It is quite strange for you not to have ceil on matalb…

Comment: The problem is that ceil() is generated inside the code for my ARM... and it doesn't support that instruction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... I solved.

The problem was in the destination environment (PSoC Creator).
As explained here http://www.cypress.com/?id=4&rID=42838 :

> Go to Project -> Build Settings -> Linker -> General -> Additional Libraries. Type m in the Additional Libraries field.
>   If you are not adding this Additional Library then you will get the following Build error "undefined reference to `sqrt'" where sqrt is a math function.

Nothing changes if the problem is with sqrt() or ceil(), because they are in the same library (math.h).

PS: thank you Engineero... your solution is very useful, and can be apprecied from other people with my problem (but in other environments).

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own `ceil` function and include it in whatever your output code is for your target device. Assuming you are generating C-code, the function would look something like:

```c
int ceil (double number) {
    if (number == 0)
        return 0;
    if (number > 0) {
        if (number - (int) number > 0)
            return (int) number + 1;
        else
            return (int) number;
    }
    else {
        if (number - (int) number < 0)
            return (int) number - 1;
        else
            return (int) number;
    }
}
```

With a prototype in your header file like:

```c
int ceil (double);
```

Now your C-code can call `integerValuedNumber = ceil(doubleValuedNumber)` and it should work. You can also do this with [macros in the C-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796639/implementation-of-ceil-function-in-c) (see nintendo's answer).

**EDIT:** I corrected my code to use proper type casting syntax for C. Basically what you are doing with the `(int) number` syntax is taking the double-valued `number` variable and forcing it to be an integer. You can find more information about [data types in C here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types), or Google "type casting C" or "data types C" for more information.

Also, some additional parenthesis might be needed, like `return ((int) number) + 1;` and similar. I am a little rusty on my C-programming, but hopefully this gets you going toward a viable solution.

**EDIT 2:** I corrected the return data type of our self-defined `ceil` function. You would want this to return an `int`, or maybe `long`. Again, check out documentation on data types in C if you are not sure what data type is appropriate for your application. If the values you are applying `ceil` to are not very large (less than +/- 2^15 for instance) then `int` is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... but not existing ceil(), also int() doesn't exist... :(

Comment: @PierpaoloCira Sorry about that, I had the wrong syntax. I corrected my answer to include the correct type-casting syntax for C. I make no guarantees that my code is exactly what you need, but it might get you started on the right path.

Comment: Thank you: this is very useful. By the way I found a different solution to my problem that uses ceil() native implementation (inside math.h library).

Comment: Ah yes, math.h. Now why didn't I think of that? That is the best solution, I am sure.